# Comparing multiple row values and assigning a number based on greater/less than

Tags: python, pandas

So I've got a large pandas dataframe of sea surface temperature anomalies ('ssta'), and each month ('Month', 1-12) has unique values for the 90th and 10th percentiles ('90th', '10th'). An example is below:

```
monlth_data

    lat     lon      time         Month  ssta       90th         10th
0   24.125  262.375  1982-01-01     1   -0.953852   1.566498    -1.620501
1   24.125  262.375  1982-01-02     1   -0.403852   1.566498    -1.620501
2   24.125  262.375  1982-01-03     1   -0.083853   1.566498    -1.620501
3   24.125  262.375  1982-01-04     1   -0.243853   1.566498    -1.620501
4   24.125  262.375  1982-01-05     1   -0.213852   1.566498    -1.620501
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
7798309 30.375  273.875 2020-12-27  12  -0.139111   1.382500    -1.377530
```

I need to create a new column (call it 'threshold') in the dataframe which will be based on the 90th and 10th values.... This new column should contain a '+1' if the ssta >= the 90th, '-1' if it <= the 10th, or 0 if in between(neither -1/+1). Here is an example of what that would look like:

```
monthly_threshold

    lat     lon      time         Month  ssta       90th         10th       threshold
0   24.125  262.375  1982-01-01     1   0.000000    1.566498    -1.620501   0
1   24.125  262.375  1982-01-01     1   -2.00000    1.566498    -1.620501   -1 
2   24.125  262.375  1982-01-01     1   2.000000    1.566498    -1.620501   +1
```

I had it working on another dataframe but I was working on a single month, so it was easy to compare all 'ssta' column values to the same percentile values. Now it's a little more complicated because there are multiple months thus multiple percentile values. Not sure if this would benefit from a for-loop, or some type of if-statement (which I'm rusty on). Any insight would be appreciated!

Below I'll show what I had working, but again it was based on one month (June):

```
SSTA_df_copy['threshold'] = ''
SSTA_df_copy.loc[SSTA_df_copy.SSTA <= SSTA_df_copy.SSTA.quantile(.1), 'threshold'] = -1
SSTA_df_copy.loc[(SSTA_df_copy.SSTA > SSTA_df_copy.SSTA.quantile(.1)) & (SSTA_df_copy.SSTA < SSTA_df_copy.SSTA.quantile(.9)), 'threshold'] = 0
SSTA_df_copy.loc[SSTA_df_copy.SSTA >= SSTA_df_copy.SSTA.quantile(.9), 'threshold'] = 1


         lat    lon     time        day  SSTA       threshold   year
604607  28.625  274.625 2002-06-30  30  -1.463335   -1          2002
89967   28.625  267.375 2013-06-30  30   0.946152   0           2013
```

Comment: `np.where(val < quant10, -1, np.where(val > quant90, 1, 0))`

Comment: u cand also add to group by mont with: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')) and then use the np condition